# How to get node from the link that has been added via WYSIWYG editor in Drupal 8?

Tags: php, wysiwyg, drupal-8

I have created an `Article` content. My `Article` content type has the `Paragraph type` entity reference field. By selecting the `Paragraph type Text`, I get the WYSIWYG editor to enter some text.

I have entered a link in the WYSIWYG editor that points to a node. How can I get that node via my `Article` content in Drupal 8?

Answer (score 0):

I would add a reference field to the `Article` content type. If you want it to show, you can display it as a rendered entity (beware of loops if you add an `Article` to an `Article`). If you want to use the node internally you can set the display to disabled on that field and then `Node->get(field_node_reference);` that node.